# How to retrieve null value from self joined table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table employee with primary key "Emp_id" and the same primary key's value in the same table's column "Manager_Id", Some employees are the manager of other employees and some are not. Some Employees have manager and some don't have manager, means the column of "Manager_ID" is null.

| Emp_id | Emp_name | Manager_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | Null |
| 2 | Ben | 3 |
| 3 | Jolly | 1 |
| 4 | Mike | 1 |
| 5 | Richard | 3 |

Here is the query I'm trying:

```
select a.Emp_Name as Employee, b.Emp_Name as Manager
from employee a
left outer join employee b on a.Emp_ID and b.Emp_ID
where a.Manager_ID = b.Emp_ID
```

I have to print Emp_name and Manager Name from only one table, and also where the Manager_ID is "Null" I want a Null value in the resultant table but I am unable to do this.

For example, I need the resultant table like this.

| Employee | Manager |
| --- | --- |
| John | Null |
| Ben | Jolly |
| Jolly | John |
| Mike | John |
| Richard | jolly |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
select e.emp_name as employee, m.emp_name as manager
from employee e
left join employee m on m.id = e.manager_id
```

Comment: Thank you So Much! Your answer make me smile thanks again. its working

Comment: @MuhammadUmar Please consider marking as an approved answer if this resolves your question.

Comment: Could you please help me little more, From Same table in Question I need employees that are not manager of any other employee.

Comment: @ProLearner You can use an anti-join to find those employees. For example: `select a.* from employee a left join employee b on b.manager_id = a.id where b.manager_id is null`.